# Storing submodules for micro services, but still using forks

Tags: git, docker, git-submodules, docker-compose, microservices

I am stumped here.  A lot of this is already in place, its just the wrapping that I cannot figure out.

We have a micro-service architecture, with many separate repositories.  We are using Docker, and Docker Compose for building and running the development environment, which works beautifully.

The question I have, is how to package up the main collection of repositories.  So if I have a folder structure like:

```
\
    service1
        .git
        Dockerfile
    service2 
        .git
        Dockerfile
    service3
        .git
        Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
    README.md
```

...Where service1, service2, service3 are each their own git repository.

My first thought was to use git submodules, which *would* work, however we enforce policies to require developers to fork repositories instead of working off the main repository due to continuous integration constraints and code reviews.  I was not overly excited about using git submodules at all, even before I thought of this caveat, so an alternative solution would be much preferred.

At the moment i can only think to write scripts to store a list of repositories; run a query for each to see if the logged-in developer has a fork of each, creating one if not, then pulling into the master folder; and then booting docker-compose.  This seems like a horrible solution though, enough so that I may just have to write docs to just tell devs how to manually do this process...

Thoughts??

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3):

I've had similar problem with workflow (with exception that I didn't use forks). Ultimately my requirements came down to 1 thing:

- As a developer, I want to run 1 command `project bootstrap` to bootstrap my environment

---

I would suggest to do few things to optimize the workflow, which worked incredibly well for me:

- store list of services in JSON file, where each service has "url", "fork_url", "name" and other common attributes required for docker-compose to understand how to handle this service. It seems like every team member on your team will have either fork url or base repo url
- build a command-line app (there are a number of options available - depends on your language of choice, for Ruby it's gem Thor, for Go it's package Cobra, etc). Usually it takes just a few hours to build a simple command-line app structure and first couple commands, but this type of automation will save you hours on a day-by-day basis and you will have a foundation to extend your command-line app as your needs increase and the concept is proven to be viable and useful. You also will have a unified interface to provision your environment across all of team members, which then becomes responsibility of a team to maintain it.
- build a `project bootstrap` command to provision your environment. For example, it will:

  - go over list of services from your JSON file:

    - do a fork if not exists
    - clone your repo
    - add another remote to your repo, which will represent fork (apart from origin)
    - will generate `docker-compose.yml` from template in a specified directory

Comment: i ended up similar to here.  I built a bash script to clone a read-only copy from the master repositories, and build out each machine.  There is also a separate script for provisioning databases and whatnot once the instances are all running.  So 2 scripts is not bad.  If a developer wants to publish changes to branches, they merely need to rename their origin remote to upstream and add their fork as the new origin.

Comment: I am not overly excited about the ability to keep this up-to-date however, I see some potential pitfalls here...

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on your workflow. Are you likely to be making changes to multiple services at once?

If you usually only make a change to one or two services at any given time, you can setup your `docker-compose.yml` to use only `image` fields (instead of `build`) , and to not use any host volumes.  With this setup, it doesn't matter where the code is checked out because the `docker-compose.yml` just uses images available to the docker daemon.

This would require you to have other `docker-compose.yml` files (or a bash script, makefile, etc) in each repo to build the images for each service.

If you need host volumes for interactive development, you use a `docker-compose.override.yml` to add them as necessary (but that would be up to the developer to point it at the right path).

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve a similar problem at work (although we don't use Docker; instead we have a `Vagrantfile` which provisions a VM for each of our microservices).

Create a `develop` repository containing your `docker-compose.yml`. Each developer should clone the `develop` repository, as well as his or her forks of the microservices, to a common directory (e.g. `~/workspace`):

```
/Users/conar/workspace
  /develop
    /docker-compose.yml
  /service1
    /Dockerfile
    /app.js
  /service2
    /Dockerfile
    /app.js
  /service3
    /Dockerfile
    /app.js
```

Your `docker-compose.yml` might look something like this:

```
service1:
  build: ../service1/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ../service1:/app
service2:
  build: ../service2/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ../service2:/app
service3:
  build: ../service3/Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - ../service3:/app
```

Now each service's `app.js` (and all other code) is available under `/app`.